# changing netmask of loopback interface

Tags: linux-networking, subnet, localhost, loopback, netmask

I can change netmask of loopback inteface (usually `lo` interface has 127.0.0.1/8):

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ifconfig
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo ifconfig lo 127.0.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 up

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ifconfig
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.255.255.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
```

What negative effects can this have? What pitfalls it hides?

Answer (score 3):

Then loopback only responds to `127.0.0.1/24`. Do not do it, there is no purpose to this non-standard configuration.

Just one thing that might be broken: Debian systems that [ensure their own hostname can be resolved](https://lists.debian.org/debian-boot/2005/06/msg00938.html) via in /etc/hosts, possibly to `127.0.1.1`.

---

Remember that on Linux `ifconfig` has been obsolete for many years.

The equivalent iproute is:

```
ip addr add 127.0.0.1/24 dev lo
ip addr del 127.0.0.1/8 dev lo
```

Comment: and what about setting lo to 127.0.0.0/16?

Comment: It should be 127.0.0.0/8. Come up with a use case of why before making the effort to make something non-standard work.

Comment: I tried to explain the use case in this post: https://superuser.com/questions/1581597/which-ip-address-to-assign-to-private-interfaces

Answer (score 1):

well, looks like it will be the future
127/16

according to this doc
https://www.ietf.org/id/draft-schoen-intarea-unicast-127-00.html

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/503076)